# Is there a way to write a custom sorting function to sort data in a column in vegalite?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am trying to create a custom sorting function in vegalite which sorts data in a column in a given order. e.g. a,b,c,d,e -> a,c,d,b,e. The function takes an array as input and gives an array as output. This behaviour is similar to factor-level in R. I know there are vega Expressions that we can use to achieve this, but I don't know how to use it in vega-lite.

EDIT:
[image]
For this plot, I am trying to sort the **weekday** column in descending order. I want to create a generalisable solution such that any column with a nominal data type can be sorted using a custom sort function.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of a chart and which aspect of it you would like to sort?

Comment: @jakevdp, I have added an example chart for my question.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The solution for re-ordering data depends on how your data and encodings are defined.